# Debugging & possible causes of distutils.dir_util.copy_tree() doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: python-3.x, distutils, copytree

I have some simple code to import a csv file of Windows File Paths e.g.`"C:/Folder/SubFolder/folder1"` to copy the contents and any subfolders to a new directory.

When I run the code I get about 1/3 of my sample returning **`doesn't exist or not a regular file`** while the other are copied successfully.

The files that are causing problems are either .docx or .pdf but equally as many were copied over successfully.

**What could be causing this issue on a local Windows 10 machine and how do I debug it further?**

```
for Submission in FilePaths.itertuples():
    Create the Path
    FolderName = Submission.Group+"-"+Submission.ID+"-"+Submission.FirstName+Submission.Surname
    DestinationPath =DestinationBasePath + Submission.Category+"\\"+ Submission.Value+"\\"+FolderName
    #Copy the source folder tree and contents to the destination 
    try:
        copy_tree(Submission.FullFilePath, DestinationPath,verbose=1)
    except Exception as Ex:
    print(Ex)
    os.listdir(Submission.FullFilePath)
```

Comment: I moved the source directory as I was using a OneDrive Folder and it appears to be working for me now. Not sure why but maybe OneDrive sync feature is preventing python accessing the file correctly

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it was connected to syncing or file locking issues which prevented the files from being copied.